# How to sort into a new DataFrame based on values within a list?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, nested-lists

For example I have:

```
[{'day': 'monday', 'sunny': 'yes', 'windy': 'yes', 'ended': 'yes'}, {'day': 'tuesday', 'sunny': 'no', 'windy': 'yes', 'ended': 'no'}]
```

The values (the name of the day, and the answers i.e. yes, no, etc.) are taken from user input (user can enter as many as they want).
I need to sort these into a DataFrame where values are organized, for example:

If it's both sunny and windy, the values must be sorted under the heading GOOD WEATHER.
If it's just sunny and not windy, it must be under HOT WEATHER, etc....
If the day has ended, nothing for that day should be shown.

How do I go about this?
After I sort the DataFrame this way, I have to write it to a csv file.
Very new to Python, so please use simpler explanations/functions etc.

Answer (score 0):

For task like this you can use `pandas`. Creating a dataframe from your sample data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'day': 'monday', 'sunny': 'yes', 'windy': 'yes', 'ended': 'yes'}, {'day': 'tuesday', 'sunny': 'no', 'windy': 'yes', 'ended': 'no'}])
```

Resulting in:

```
    day     sunny   windy   ended
0   monday  yes     yes     yes
1   tuesday     no  yes     no
```

And than you can could check different conditions. For example:

```
# check if HOT WEATHER
for row in range(len(df)):
if df.loc[row,"sunny"] == "yes" and df.loc[row,"windy"] == "yes":

    print(f" {df.loc[row,'day']} was a day with HOT WEATHER")
```

With the `loc` function you can give the row index and the column name in squared brackets to return the value in the specified cell. Maybe append the "HOT WEATHER" and so on to a list or create a new column in the dataframe.

Comment: How would I use a for loop to iterate through them all? Using iterrows is not recommended, apparently. So if using list comprehension, could you tell me how to do so?

Comment: I updated my post to include a loop to iterate through each row of the dataframe. (Could not test this right now)

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are getting the input in list of Jsons, that is dicts in Python.

So storing that input in a variable and creating a new empty dataframe having 2 cols named *GOOD WEATHER* and *HOT WEATHER* like below:

```
import pandas as pd

test = [{'day': 'monday', 'sunny': 'yes', 'windy': 'yes', 'ended': 'yes'}, {'day': 'tuesday', 'sunny': 'yes', 'windy': 'yes', 'ended': 'no'}]
Mydataframe = pd.DataFrame({'GOOD WEATHER': [], 'HOT WEATHER': []})
```

Then we're looping through the list of inputs, which will be dicts for us and checking the conditions which you have mentioned. You can add more conditions in the nested if-else.

```
for data in test:
    if data['ended'] == 'no':
        if data['sunny'] == 'yes':
            if data['windy'] == 'yes':
                Mydataframe = Mydataframe.append([{'GOOD WEATHER':data}], ignore_index=True)
            else:
                Mydataframe = Mydataframe.append([{'HOT WEATHER':data}], ignore_index=True)
```

So, whenever conditions gets true *Mydataframe.append* command will add the whole data of values in the desired column.

PS: If you want the data separated, you can create two dataframes. One for *GOOD WEATHER* and other for *HOT WEATHER*.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but somehow the dataframe is empty? I've followed what you've said, but it's empty. Sorry if I'm missing something obvious

Comment: From your input data, it'll be empty because there are two data in the list, one has _'ended': 'yes'_, so that data won't be added. And for other _'sunny':'no'_, so the condition will not satisfy and data won't be added. Try to change in the conditions or in the data to get results. You can use my _test_ list to get results.